# How to sum values in single row with Rails 4?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model, `Book`, with the information about that book (`title`, `author`, `publisher` etc), and it also has `views`, `downloads`, `shares`.

But, What I want to do is sort the books by "popularity", which in my terms is `views + downloads + shares` for that particular row, then I'd optionally like to display the 'popularity score' associated with a record.

Thanks!

Comment: So, whats the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure How I would create this query. Heh. I honestly don't even know what to google..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
records = Book.select("books.*, views + downloads + shares AS popularity").order("popularity DESC")
# => access popularity as record.popularity
```

Comment: This is great! I will try. By the way, do you think this is a stupid thing to do for performance? I'm not sure if I should just have a 4th column that would be updated. If it's not a huge performance hit I'd rather just do it this way

Comment: If the table `books` is huge and you need this data often then it is better to have another column. Other option (which I prefer) is to use caching as I would do that anyways to speed up my views.

Comment: Some databases will allow the calculated popularity to be defined as a derived column, and it can also be indexed to aid with finding the most (or least) popular books quickly.